# Beamer: Overfull hbox in headline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, boxes, warnings

I try to redefine the header of my frames, but for some mysterious reason I get an overfull hbox of 1.6 points or slightly more:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{times}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\relax
 \hbox{\relax
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}
 }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Normal}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Fragile}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- The problem must be related to the font I use, since if I remove the
  `\usepackage{times}` directive, the overfull `hbox` is of different size.
- I tried changing out the relative sizes of the two `beamercolorbox`es, but then the deader does not cover the entire frame, which is very obvious when the header is of a different color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a `%` at the end of `\end{beamercolorbox}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{times}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\relax
 \hbox{\relax
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}% <----- HERE!
 }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Normal}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Fragile}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Gee, you are right. This is so embarrassing!

Comment: @YossiGil Whenever the length changes with the font, suspect a spurious space.